# Big integer literals are not available in the configured target environment

Tags: web3.js

I am getting error Big integer literals are not available in the configured target environment ("chrome87", "edge88", "es2020", "firefox78", "safari13" + 2 overrides)  node_modules/@solana/web3.js/lib/index.browser.esm.js:4743:20
[image: Error SS 1]

[image: Error SS 2]

Answer (score 3):

You need to configure Target Environment to "ES2020" or "ESNext".

Search for tsconfig.js

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ESNext", 
    "module": "ESNext",
  }
}
```

If you are using Vite or Webpack you can configure it in their config files.
Read more here:

https://webpack.js.org/configuration/

https://vitejs.dev/config/

Hope it helps...