# ng build --configuration production --aot --build-optimizer --optimization

Tags: javascript

Optimization error [main.2d5f2a771afdf2fe.js]: X [ERROR] Big integer literals are not available in the configured target environment ("chrome103.0", "edge108.0", "firefox102.0", "ios12.2", "opera93.0", "safari14.1")

```
main.2d5f2a771afdf2fe.js:179354:137:
  179354 │ ...ORTED_MODULE_6__/* .getGasPrice */ .o)(client)) * 120n / 100n;
         ╵                                                             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

### my tsConfig.json

{
"compileOnSave": false,
"compilerOptions": {
"baseUrl": "./",
"outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
"sourceMap": true,
"declaration": false,
"module": "ESNext",
"moduleResolution": "node",
"emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
"experimentalDecorators": true,
"skipDefaultLibCheck": true,
"skipLibCheck": true,
"importHelpers": true,
"target": "ESNext",
"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
"typeRoots": [
"node_modules/@types"
],
"lib": [
"es2020",
"ESNext",
"dom"
],
"useDefineForClassFields": false
}
}

### angular.json

"production": {
"fileReplacements": [
{
"replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
"with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
},
{
"replace": "src/firebase-messaging-sw.js",
"with": "src/push-notifications/fcm/production/firebase-messaging-sw.js"
}
],
"optimization": true,
"outputHashing": "all",
"namedChunks": false,
"extractLicenses": true,
"buildOptimizer": true,
"budgets": [
{
"type": "initial",
"maximumWarning": "2mb",
"maximumError": "5mb"
},
{
"type": "anyComponentStyle",
"maximumWarning": "6kb"
}
],
"serviceWorker": true,
"ngswConfigPath": "ngsw-config.json"
},

Comment: Looks like a duplicate: https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/2514/big-integer-literals-are-not-available-in-the-configured-target-environment

Answer (score 1):

When i updated browserlistrc >0.1 to >0.5 its working good